# HTTPS web addresses with Indy IdHTTP in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder, indy10

I am using the code below in C++Builder XE4 VCL 32bit. I am using the Indy components, version 10.6.0.497.

I have been using `IdHTTP->Get()` with HTTP addresses that have now changed to HTTPS. I believe I need to create a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` component and add it to `TIdHTTP` as its `IOHandler`.

When I try to do this, the code below gives the error:

> E2451 Undefined symbol 'TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL'

The error is on the code, `std::auto_ptr<TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL>`.

I am not sure why `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` is undefined, because I have Indy installed and can use `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` as a traditional component from the component palette.

Can anyone show me how I can set this code up to use HTTPS addresses?

```
std::auto_ptr<TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL> Local_IOHandler( new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL( NULL ) );
//error: E2451 Undefined symbol 'TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL'
//error: E2299 Cannot generate template specialization from 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>'


std::auto_ptr<TIdHTTP> Local_IdHTTP( new TIdHTTP( NULL ) );
Local_IdHTTP->Name="MyLocalHTTP";
Local_IdHTTP->HandleRedirects=true;
Local_IdHTTP->IOHandler=Local_IOHandler;

TStringStream *jsonToSend = new TStringStream;

UnicodeString GetURL = "https://chartapi.finance.yahoo.com/instrument/1.0/CLZ17.NYM/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv/";

jsonToSend->Clear();
try
{
    Local_IdHTTP->Get(GetURL, jsonToSend);
}
catch (const Exception &E)
{
    ShowMessage( E.Message );
    //error: IOHandler value is not valid
}
```

Comment: And BTW, 10.6.0.497 is an old version of Indy.  The current version is 10.6.2.5422.  There have been a lot of changes and fixes between 10.6.0 and 10.6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to do this the code below gives the error E2451 Undefined symbol 'TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL'

Add `#include <IdSSLOpenSSL.hpp>` to your code.

> I am not sure why 'TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL' is Undefined because I have Indy installed and can use 'TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL' as a traditional component from the compoenent pallet?

Dropping a component onto your Form at design-time auto-generates any necessary `#include` statements for you.  `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` is no different.

That being said, once you get that fixed, you cannot assign a `std::auto_ptr` itself to the `IOHandler`.  You need to use its `get()` method to get the object pointer:

```
Local_IdHTTP->IOHandler = Local_IOHandler.get();
```

And you should consider using `std::auto_ptr` for your `TStringStream` as well:

```
std::auto_ptr<TStringStream> json( new TStringStream );
Local_IdHTTP->Get(GetURL, json.get());
// use json as needed...
```

Though in this situation, I would suggest using the overloaded version of `TIdHTTP::Get()` that returns a `String` instead, there is no benefit to using a `TStringStream`:

```
String json = Local_IdHTTP->Get(GetURL);
// use json as needed...
```